# Conditionally add an item in list initialization

Tags: c#, list

I want to add some range of items to my list initialization but sometimes I don't want to add an item based on a condition , I tried below with ternary operator , but it adds null to my list. Is there a way I can completely skip adding a particular item if condition is met ? I can do this without using initialization in a separate if block but I am looking for a solution which can be done in same initialization statement. To be more clear with my problem ,my list should have different order of items based on a flag

```
var myListByOrder= new List<Object>();   

if(flag)
{

 MyListByOrder.AddRange( new []
            {
                item1,
                item2,
                condition ? item3: null,
                item 4,
                item 5

            });
 }
else
 {
   MyListByOrder.AddRange( new []
            {
                item5,
                item3,
                condition? item7 :null                    
                item 1,
                item 2

            });
 }
```

Now just because of a condition I dont want to break the readability of code and provide extra if-else, Is there a solution to it , which can keep this same and skip the elements if condition is met. Another way is, I can remove the nulls from array after filling them in above way.

Comment: You aren't initializing a list, you're adding an array's items into an already existing list. The collection initialization syntax is similar to the array's, eg `var MyList=new List<item>{ item1, item2}`. Where do those items come from? It would be easier to modify that code and simply *not* produce whatever isn't needed.

Comment: so where do those items come from? This question is incomplete. If they're produced by an iterator, you can skip items you don't want. If they're produced by a query, you can use `Where`. You could even use a simple `condition ? new[]{i1,i2,i3}: new []{i1,i2}`. Or `condition ? new List<I>{i1,i2,i3}: new List<I>{i1,i2}`

Comment: it would be nice if collection initializers could have syntax like this:     condition? item

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this pattern occurs a lot in your code, you could consider creating a couple of extension methods that can be used to build a method chain for appending items to a `List<T>`.

Something like this:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> Append<T>(this List<T> list, params T[] values)
    {
        list.AddRange(values);
        return list;
    }

    public static List<T> AppendIf<T>(this List<T> list, bool condition, params T[] values)
    {
        return condition ? list.Append(values) : list;
    }
}
```

And then build the list in this way:

```
myListByOrder
    .Append(item1, item2)
    .AppendIf(condition, item3)
    .Append(item4, item5);
```

Answer (score -1):

No, array initialisers must be of a fixed length known at compile time.

But there are plenty of alternatives as I'm sure you know. If you're adding items to a list anyway, you might as well add them in separate statements.

Comment: the question is about Collection initializers, don't see what it has to do with array initializers

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis `new [] { ... }`, as in the question, is an array initializer.

Comment: indeed, didn't notice they were passing arrays to AddRange and thus using array initializer. Can use list initializers directly though so why go via intermediate array and have extra cost? (btw SO doesn't let one undo their older vote if answer isn't edited - strange policy)